# how to recover mistakenly deleted root user line in /etc/passwd

Tags: root, passwd

I had an accident with /etc/passwd - using putpwent(), I replaced the first line of /etc/passwd with mine.
Unfortunately this line used to belong to root.
Now I don't have root permission, and I can't change it back.
The file belongs to user 0 group root:
`-rw-r--r-- 1 0 root 1.8K Jan  9 11:33 passwd`

Any idea how to recover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot using any LiveCD Linux like Ubuntu, SystemRescueCD ..etc
Then locate your partition containing `/etc` :

```
# Using root user of the LiveCD session.
fdisk -l
```

This will show you all partitions. Now mount them one by one

```
mkdir /mypartition
mount /dev/sd<x> /mypartition
```

Until you locate the partition with your /etc.

Now you can edit your `passwd` file to recover it to the right version.

Answer (score 3):

When the bootloader shows up, add

```
init=/bin/bash
```

instead of booting normally edit kernel parameters, so for different distro you can find your solution but it should be according to your needs :

```
mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1
```

and change your root credentials and then it should be ok

Comment: Well I didn't think to this one that can also work

Comment: Since I don't have root user, I'm afraid I'll not be able to start a single user session. what do you think?

Comment: at least you can try, from my point of view root user must be initiated with init=bin/bash

Comment: @RanRegev The bootloader is before loading kernel and going into multi or single user session.

Answer (score 2):

What should work on most systems:

- Download a live linux distro
- Boot on the live linux
- Mount your partition where the file is
- Authenticate as root on the live linux
- Use `chroot`  to change your root to your partition
- Edit your file with any editor: `vi`, `nano`, `ed` ?

---

**Edit 1:**

- Or you can also consider to use `passwd` to change root password in your new root

Comment: @Zelda why any form of sympathy like good luck or It is a pleasure is remove every time someone use them ? what's the problem with being polite ?

Comment: **You** write it only once but you force others to many times waste their precious time to read through non-essential parts of an answer (or question). Better answer and question have no "thank you", "good luck", "I would like to know what ..." instead "What ...", etc. Keep it Answers and Questions crisp, that makes them better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another account on the machine and still can do `sudo` in there (i.e. `sudo` asks for the accounts password and not `root` password). You can use that to get `root` permissions and change `/etc/passwd`.